# Azure and IIS Windows Auth

Tags: windows, azure, authentication, iis

I would appreciate any help that can be offered. I would like to achieve the following in Azure and having tried various tutorials using lots of different configurations I am still unable to achieve what seems quite simple.

I would like to set the default IIS homepage on an Azure VM to use Windows Authentication. I would like to Add a user or group from my local on-premise Active Directory, which is linked to an Azure Active Directory using 'Azure AD Connect'. Finally I would like to login to a client machine on my local on-premise Active Directory, and be able to browse to the Azure VM IIS default homepage without having to enter a username and password, as I am already authenticated having logged into the local Active Directory.

I am happy to try various setups and scenarios, so if you can help please shout up.

Thanks

Andy

Comment: you would need adfs for that

Comment: I have already looked at this tutorial on ADFS:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Azure-Active-Directory-Videos-Demos/Configuring-AD-FS-for-user-sign-in-with-Azure-AD-Connect

However this requires you to sign in to the ADFS Proxy, or at least seems to. I would like to miss this step as I am already signed into the client pc as a domain user.

Comment: Can anyone help on this?